# Nautilus not opening Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, 20.04

I recently upgraded to 20.04. I am facing trouble opening Nautilus (Files), the cursor starts spinning but nothing happens next.

This is the error I get when I type `nautilus` in the terminal.

```
nautilus: symbol lookup error: nautilus: undefined symbol: pango_attr_insert_hyphens_new
```

EDIT:
Output of `apt-cache policy nautilus libpango-1.0-0` is

```
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libpango-1.0-0:
  Installed: 1.44.7-2ubuntu4
  Candidate: 1.44.7-2ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 1.44.7-2ubuntu4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and `ldd /usr/bin/nautilus| grep pango` gives

```
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f082c265000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f082c020000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f082ae06000)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy nautilus libpango-1.0-0` and `ldd /usr/bin/nautilus| grep pango` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1256201/edit).

Comment: Added the edits

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove local libraries with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
```

and then try to launch Nautilus.

Comment: Thank you. This worked

Comment: Great! So you can accept my answer here.