# Black Screen after Boot, after trying to fix Nautilus, after updating to 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, updates, nautilus, ppa

I have a problem with my Ubuntu machine. After updating from 19.10 to 20.04 my Nautilus woudnt open anymore. I tried the solution from this [Nautilus not opening Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256201/nautilus-not-opening-ubuntu-20-04) thread.

- sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
- sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0
- sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0

It didnt work, and now after a reboot I cant log in anymore. I also tried after that with pressing ctrl alt f5, and trying sudo update to try to install the packages i removed but it gives me an error:

- Err:5 https://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu groovy Release
- 404 Not Found (IP: 91.189.95.83 80)

and

- E: The repository https://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu groovy Release does not have a release file
- Updating from such a repository cant be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
- See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

any help would be highly appreciate, since I was looking for hours for a solution but didnt find any

Thanks ahead

Comment: How exactly did you upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04? Because using `update-manager` or `do-release-upgrade` (the recommended process) should remove those PPAs from your system.

Comment: the popup came up to upgrade and then i just updated, first it was a partial update and then i did the full upgrade

Comment: okay i just fixed it myself, with help from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271214/libpango-borked-system-ubuntu-20-04
ran these commands and it booted up again: 
sudo apt install --reinstall libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0